# Get a SharePoint list Id using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, nintex

I'm trying to open the list settings page of the list called 'Project Intake' on Nintex Form. However, it errors as soon as I change the name of the list. I was hoping to have a dynamic solution which is not in relation with the title of the list but `listTemplateId` as it is unique. Please let me know if anybody can help me with a better solution.

Below is the code for it:

```
    // Open PRM List Configuration Process Link
    function OpenBWPRMConfigurationProcess() 
    {
        var listTitle = "Project Intake";    
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
        var web = context.get_web();    
        list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);    
        context.load(list, 'Id');    
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,Success2), Function.createDelegate(this,Error)); 
    } 
    function Success2(listTitle) 
    { 
        var listId = list.get_id();     
        BuildConfigureLinkWithListId(listId); 
    } 
    function BuildConfigureLinkWithListId (listId) 
    {  
        var firstbit = "/_layouts/15/BrightWork/PRMRequestListSettings.aspx?List={";  
        var endbit = "}";  
    
        window.open("Site URL" + firstbit + listId + endbit,'_blank'); 
    }
    // Open PRM List Settings Link
    function OpenBWPRMListSettingsLink() 
    {
        var listTitle = "Project Intake";    
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
        var web = context.get_web();    
        list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);    
        context.load(list, 'Id');    
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,Success3), Function.createDelegate(this,Error)); 
    } 
    function Success3(listTitle) 
    {
        var listId = list.get_id();    
        BuildListSettingsLinkWithListId(listId); 
    } 
    function BuildListSettingsLinkWithListId (listId) 
    {
        var firstbit = "/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=";  
        var endbit = "";  
        //var redirecturl = "&Source=./";  
        window.open("Site URL" + firstbit + listId + endbit,'_blank');  
    } 
    function Error() 
    {
        alert('Request failed. '); 
    }
```

- SharePoint Version: SharePoint 2019 on-premise;
- List Name: Project Intake (can be deferred);
- listTemplateId: 737

Comment: There can be multiple lists in a site which are created using same base list template, right?

Comment: @GaneshSanap No, it is a unique list in the site and listTemplateId is a unique ID to that list.

Comment: listTemplateId is not unique. In SharePoint list, the most unique value would be "GUID" (GUID) and "ID" (number) column

Comment: Hi @RadityoArdi, we have a custom solution, which introduces a custom list type that makes a unique list in a site which cannot be duplicated. Therefore, I needed a solution to address listTemplateId in the code given above.

Comment: let me see if I can help you. So far I can't succeed using SP.Runtime.js within my SharePoint Online. hang on.

Comment: Hey, no issues. Let me know if you have a solution. Thanks